# What is the difference between const and static vars?

Tags: php, static, constants

If I have a class and want to have some static vars, which would be the correct way to declare them?

For example

class Foo{
      public static $var1
      public static $var2
      public static $var3

......

}

OR

class Foo{
      const $var1
      const $var2
      const $var3

......

}

both ways let me use Foo::var1. But I dont know well which is the correct way and/or if there is any adventage using one way or the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685922/php5-const-vs-static and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163975/php-oop-constant-vs-static-variables.

Answer (score 4):

`const` variables can't be modified.  The `static` ones can.  Use the right one for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`class Foo{const $var1....}`  is a syntax error (don't need `$` after `const`)

Answer (score 0):

In [conventional coding standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php) we name consts like `Foo::CONST1` in all caps without any `$` in the name.  So you don't need to be confused between consts and variables.

As others have noted, you define the value of a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) once, and you can't change that value during the remainder of a given PHP request.

Whereas you can change the value of a [static class variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) as many times as you need to.