# php constant in oops being changed by the class object

Tags: php, oop

Today i was reading constant in oops and got confused by a piece of code na dcould not make out the reason for it the code is given below:

```
<?php
class myClass1
{
    const ID=1;
    private $name;

    public function get_name()
    {
        return $this->name ."<br>";
    }

    public function set_name($setName)
    {
        $this->name=$setName;
    }
}

$myClass1_object = new myClass1();

$myClass1_object->ID=2;

print("<br>".$myClass1_object->ID);
?>
```

I want to know the reason that how can a constant variable i.e const ID=1 is being changed by the the class object i.e  $myClass1_object->ID=2; and in print statement i get the updated value i.e 2.

Comment: This contant is being changed by magical method `__set()`

Comment: You print another field (created by accessing it via magic method), not constant. Access constant using this syntax: `myClass1::ID`

Comment: One thing yet. What is aim to use CONST in class? Senseless. You have static properties

Comment: @turson Some people are anti-static because they are evil. You can use Definitions though

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685922/php5-const-vs-static

Comment: ok then is there any method by which i can prevent the value of ID by being changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to access undefined object property PHP creates it for you:

```
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->hello = 'world';
```

So you created just another field ID when you try to access your constant such way. Try to print constant value at the end of your script:

```
echo myClass1::ID;
```

and it should still be 1