# public static final String in PHP

Tags: php

What would be the equivalent of `public static final String str = "Foo";` in PHP?

I have a class like so:

```
class MyClass {

    public $TYPE_REGULAR = 'regular';

    public function display($type) {
        if($type===$this->TYPE_REGULAR) {
            return "This is a regular object";
        }
        return "This is not a regular object";
    }
}
```

In the above example, I don't want `$TYPE_REGULAR` to be a member property. I want it to be something like `public static final String` of Java.

Thanks.

Comment: pretty sure `const` is what you are after here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In PHP you have to use `const` for variables.
>
> You can use `final` only for classes and methods.

In your situation:

```
const TYPE_REGULAR = 'regular'; // public is by default
```

Also read more about difference between static and const in PHP:
[PHP5: const vs static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685922/php5-const-vs-static)

Comment: I think it should be `TYPE_REGULAR` without the `$` sign.

Answer (score 0):

Use `const`.

```
...

const TYPE_REGULAR = 'regular';

...

// access it inside the class using
self::TYPE_REGULAR
```

See [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).