# get current instance of class in PHP

Tags: php, class, instance

how do i get access to a current instance of class that's already running in PHP?

in my one PHP class, I want to call a function from another that's already running as a server. so i cant create a new instance.

thanks.

p a

Comment: I don't understand, especially the part about running a class as a server. Can you show some code?

Comment: hi pekka the code is really complicated there's a lot of classes. but basically its a websocket server written in PHP that you can find here: http://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket. I am basically trying to call one of the functions in this server from the outside (for example, if a user clicks a button, call send data function inside the server).

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called a singleton.

With a Singleton you can have only one instance of your class running on the server.

To do so you must :

- store your instance in your class as a `static` field
- have a `private` constructor so you can't create instances yourself
- have a `static` method which call the constructor once, and return the only instance

---

**Resources :**

- [Wikipedia - Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
- [php.net - singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton)

**On the same topic :**

- [Creating the Singleton design pattern in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5)
- [What is so bad about Singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)