# How to define global functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, global

How can I define a global function which would be accessible from any page?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In file *include.php*:

```
function myGlobalFunction() {
    // Do something
}
```

Then in every page you want to use it:

```
include 'include.php';
myGlobalFunction();
```

Comment: If function has to be _include_-ed every time it's needed then this does not answer question. The only thing global about  _myGlobalFunction_ is it's name.

Answer (score 52):

If you want your function to always be available, without including it, do this:

1. Create your function in a PHP file.
2. In your php.ini file, search for the option `auto_prepend_file` and add your PHP file to that line, like this:

   ```
   `auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/my_superglobal_function.php"`
   ```

   Or if you write it with a non absolute path, like this:

   `auto_prepend_file = "my_superglobal_function.php"`

   It will look in your `include_path` in `php.ini` to find the file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, cause it solves the problem for **any page**.

Comment: This is not the best solution cause you (or other people, who cannot even know about that) have to modify every environment in which your application is used

Comment: @Lambrusco this does solve the question though; a function that is included somewhere within your own code would not truely be global, would it?

Comment: it _is_ a great solution if you have a lot of functions you use in all projects, like mysql things or stuff like this, or you improve/overwrite some existing funtions. If you want to share your work you can include_once the function in all cases.

Comment: @Thelambofgoat Your objection is not supportive, because it also works with htaccess

Answer (score 43):

You could declare a function inside a function. Be careful to call the outside function only once or you'll get an error.

```
class MyClass {

  function declareGlobalsFn () {
    // Functions declared inside a function have global scope

    function globalfn1() {echo "fn1";}

    function globalfn2() {echo "fn2";}
  }
}

$ob = new MyClass();
$ob->declareGlobalsFn();

globalfn1(); // fn1
globalfn2(); // fn2
```

Comment: wow, this is for me a new way of creating functions. It looks like a good question for a PHP exam. Will this code execute or not? Are this closures or not? :-) Can you tell me when this is a best practice? As far as I can see perform include or require the same function, but the latter two are imho better for maintenance. Anyhow, for the good or the worse, you learned me something. That is why I upvoted your answer. Although none of you really answered the question. That answer is simply: all functions that are not class members have global scope.

Comment: I don't see any good reason for defining functions this way. Among other things, `declareGlobalsFn()` can't be called twice, or you get: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare globalfn1()`

Comment: That's also new to me. There is one very good reason: you can combine declaration with inheritance by `calling parent::declareGlobalsFn()` and avoid an error by [checking for existence](http://php.net/manual/de/function.function-exists.php) first.

Comment: @x-yuri these local functions can be used to optimize a non-tail recursive function into a tail recursive one. However, it seems that php doesn't perform tail call optimisations as opposed [here](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/tail-call-optimization-elimination-php/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171807/does-php-optimize-tail-recursion), so it won't really help here. However, it is possible to chop down a very long method into smaller well named digestible peaces. With these named peaces of code it should lead to a (still big) function with higher readability and less comments.

Comment: awesome! was looking for this :)

Comment: You can prevent duplicate declaration using `if(!function_exists('globalfn1')){ function globalfn1(){ ... }}`

Comment: You could also prevent duplicate declarations by making the class a [Singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5).

Comment: Prevent duplicate by checking if the function is already defined and returning early if so. This actually looks pretty useful to me as something to have in a library. Putting global functions that people might not want in the root namespace is sort of rude, but it isn't possible to namespace free functions in PHP. If I include a file with  MyClass then I'd have the option to call declareGlobalsFn only if I want to.

Comment: What if `MyClass` is in a namespace? Can I still define functions in the global scope? I tried but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: This looks more like a bug than a solution.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [luarwo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753616/4795539), you can declare the function right in your class constructor. This could make your class a sort of function library, where the functions are accessible from any page where you create your class instance.

**Sandbox\MyGameLib**

```
<?php
namespace Sandbox;
class MyGameLib {
    public function __construct() {
        if (!function_exists('loveGame')) {
            function loveGame($game) {
                print "The game $game is awesome";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Seesaw**

```
<?php
namespace Seesaw;
use Sandbox\MyGameLib;

$m = new MyGameLib();
loveGame('Tempest');
```

> The game Tempest is awesome

Comment: This is actually wrong since the function will not be global but part of the `Sandbox` namespace.

Comment: This needs some clarification. This is a better way of doing what OP _probably_ wants. I am assuming that OP, not knowing how `include` works, means accessible from anywhere and not necessarily, literally, in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

> Then in every page you want to use it:
>
> `include 'include.php'; myGlobalFunction();`

-

> Put it in an include, then include it.

This *technically* may not be correct, depending on the context.

'Page' could be perceived as 'file'. For example, "You must include the function's file within each file you want to use the function".

Once a function is defined in your program, it can be accessed from anywhere moving forward up until the program has finished executing.

Say you have this:

**index.php**:

```
<?php
    function echo_1() {
       echo 1;
    }

    echo_1();

    require 'boot.php';
```

---

**boot.php**

```
<?php
    include_once 'page.php';

    echo_1();
    echo_9342949();
```

---

**page.php**

```
<?php
    function echo_9342949() {
      echo 9342949;
    }

    echo_1();
```

---

With that, your output would be `1119342949`.

Of course, when you say 'page' you may literally mean a directly accessed stand-alone '*page file*', in which case the answers from the other users will suffice. However, if you're looking to use the same function from different locations throughout your program, simply define it before you intend to use it and you can access it anywhere moving forward regardless of scope.

> However, if you're looking to use the same function from different
>   locations throughout your program, simply define it before you intend
>   to use it and you can access it anywhere moving forward regardless of
>   scope.

This of course isn't true for things like *class functions*, but for normal functions this remains true.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [PHP Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software)) with autoloading. You can take a look at the laravel implementation for a helper function.

In brief, Just define your helper function script in the autoloading section and the PHP composer will take care of it.

Note: Do not forget to include the autoload.php file at the top level of your project.

*[Basic usage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)*

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an include, and then include it.