# PHP methods as functions // change scope

Tags: php, methods

I have a class such as

```
class myClass {

    function myMethod(){

        include(something);

    }

    function callMe(){

    }

}
```

I want to call `callMe()`from the include rather than`$this->callMe();`

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Is there any reason behind that ?

Comment: Because all the calls in the include file is going to only be calling methods within that object anyways, there is no point to keep writing $this over and over in the code. Also I want to somewhat hide the fact that it is even in an object anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class myClass {

    public function myMethod(){

        include(something);

    }

    public function callMe(){

    }

}
```

Some other php file:

```
include 'myClass.php';
$myClass = new myClass();
$myClass->callMe();
```

Comment: The person who down voted this answer.
There was no need to do that.
Bolli was just trying to make the question sense clear.

Comment: Not my dv, but if you want to make something clear, you need to comment and ask the OP. Your answer isn't relevant to the question either. The OP does not want to know how to call the `callMe()` from outside.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Ah okay - I thought he asked how to run the function from another file - through the 'include(something') in 'myMethod'.

Comment: No sorry, looking for a way to call the method as callMe() rather than $this->callMe()

Comment: @variable I don't think you can do that - you are trying to change the syntax of  PHP? Then you would have to stop using it as a class and instead just use a regular .php file and include that in something.php.

Comment: @variable or look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458837/how-to-define-global-functions-in-php