# get_magic_quotes_gpc going away, how to bulk update the code

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I have thousands of instances of calls to get_magic_quotes_gpc. Since get_magic_quotes_gpc is going away, I found a recommendation to simply replace call with "false".

Then the code:

```php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $cell = stripslashes($cell);
}
```

would become:

```php
if (false) {
    $cell = stripslashes($cell);
}
```

This would require finding and replacing each instance.

I have made a few updates to test the one-at-time solution but is there a bulk or universal solution or do I have to hire additional programmers to sift thru the files? Otherwise when PHP V8 comes along, there are going to be a lot crashes.

Answer (score 5):

You could always define your own replacement function in a [globally included file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18075712/283366)...

```php
if (!function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    function get_magic_quotes_gpc() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/9C6Ui

Answer (score 4):

Can be done in a single shell command:

```bash
$ sed -i 's/get_magic_quotes_gpc()/false/g' *
```

Or, to apply this only to `.php` files:

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/get_magic_quotes_gpc()/false/g' *
```