# change a variable value in another function

Tags: php

I need some help with my php code. This is my code

```
class myclass extends anotherclass {

    var $bAlert;

    function myclass($var) {
        parent::anotherclass($var);
        $this->bAlert = false;
    }

function alert() {
        $this->bAlert = 'true';
        return;
    }

function display() {
        if(!$this->bAlert) {
           return;
        }
        return 'blah blah';
    }
}
```

Now what i want, I have a function to show something on screen when display() is called thats not the problem but i only want it to show up after alert() is called. So here is what i thought but it has a problem. I want to permanently change the value of $bAlert to true once alert() is called and of course it doesn't happen. So, anybody got any other bright ideas or any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: SO why you dont put $this->alert() at the first line of display() function ? This way you will always run alert() when you run display()

Comment: Sure you mean `'true'` and not the constant `true` inside the `alert()` function?

Comment: And it looks like you use a really outdated php version (or at least its syntax). Since version 5 constructors are called `__construct()` and not by the class names any more.

Comment: nop i need to call this alert() from outside. For example. A user logs in and i call alert() and when the page loads i called display(). So, it will only showup when the user logged in.

Comment: sorry about the 'true' its true actually. Its a cms so i have to follow code convection and have  to use class names.

Comment: Not sure what problem you face, actually. Calling `alert()` certainly _does_ change the value of `bAlert` inside the object `alert()` is called on. Might it be you want to have the value changed in _all_ objects of class myclass? Then you should take a look at static variables. Static variables are shared between all instanciated objects of a class.

Answer (score 2):

Use singleton classes

Please visit [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5) for more info on singleton classes

**EDIT:**

Or you can use static variables and methods

**EDIT:**

See this code:

```
<?php 
class myclass extends anotherclass {
    static public $bAlert;
    function myclass($var) {
        parent::anotherclass($var);
        self::$bAlert = false;
    }
    static function alert() {
        self::$bAlert = 'true';
        return;
    }
    function display() {
        if(!self::$bAlert) {
        return;
        }
        return 'blah blah';
    }
}
```

Comment: if it will be only used within this class, you might want to consider changing `pulic static $bAlert` to `private static $bAlert`, though some frameworks don't work well with that. @Prashank You mentioned earlier that $bAlert can't be a boolean because of it's within a frame work? Then why you compare it like an boolean? a `String` will always be **`true`**.

Comment: hmm! this didn't worked for me and maybe the reason is still same. calling the class from anywhere sets it to false again. I will go with the temporary cookie way. I was trying to avoid it but looks like its the only option now. But many thanks for your reply, its very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll add my implementation for clarity

*Note:* For this to work, you need to use `session_start();` in all the script-pages you need the user to be logged-in.

```
class MyClass extends AnotherClass
{
  public static
    $bAlert = false;

  // This is the magic you need!
  public function __construct()
  {
    // Check if the session-var exists, then put it into the class
    if ( array_key_exists('bAlert', $_SESSION) ) {
      self::$bAlert = $_SESSION['bAlert'];

    // Set session with the default value of the class
    } else {
      $_SESSION['bAlert'] = self::$bAlert;
    }
  }

  function setAlert($alertValue = true)
  {
    // Used type-juggle in-case of weird input
    self::$bAlert = (bool) $alertValue;

    // Not needed, but looks neat.
    return;                 
  }

  function display($message = 'Lorum ipsum')
  {
    // This part will **only** work when it's a boolean
    if ( !self::$bAlert ) {
      return;
    }

    return $message;
  }
}
```

Btw, if you use classes in PHP5+ try using `function __construct(){}` instead of `function MyClassName(){}`. I know it looks weird compared with other programming-languages, but in PHP5+ it just works better.

For a better understanding of Classes & Objects and Sessions, this documentation might be useful:

- [PHP Classes & Objects; The Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)
- [PHP Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: After reading your question again, I'll also add a small implementation of Sessions

Comment: Actually i already used my cookie way to do this and i doubt i can add session_start() in a CMS cuz it has its own session system but i really appreciate your help. Thank you again.

Comment: oh, that's pretty easy to replace with cookies. Anyway, be careful with cookies, there are a lot of countries with specific law's about do's and dont's. Just replace `$_SESSION` with `$_COOKIE` and you also don't need to worry about the `session_start()` then. Also keep in mind that cookies are browser depended, this could break a consistant user-experience of the overall site/application