# In what scenario would constructors be private or protected?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Is there such a situation where __construct() would be declared anything but public?

If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common example for making the constructor private or protected is implementing the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203359/318508) for a PHP example.

Comment: What would such a design pattern be used for?  Forgive me for the "noob" question.

Comment: @DustinL. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323

Comment: In other languages, they are used for classes that should have only once instance: resource managers, caches, loggers, etc.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks! Love the flowchart as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

I also use private constructors when using the [builder pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) inside the class, and also when adding [static factory methods](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) for a class.

Both can help you to avoid creating too many constructors, and also help you to create constructors with meaningful names.
For example instead of:

```
new Robot(2, 4, 255, 0, 0)
```

You can create with builder:

```
RobotBuilder.withNumberOfArms(2).withColor(255,0,0).withNumberOfEyes(2).build()
```

As the builder is inside the class, only it can call its private constructor.

For static factory methods, you can see that these:

```
public static Robot createFourArmedRobot();
public static Robot createBlindRobot();
```

are much more meaningful for an other developer than two constructors with custom parameters.
(More relating to OOP than php)

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do __construct() as private for singleton pattern that is related to design patterns to know more about it visit this page - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern