# Set class static variable to object

Tags: php

I have been unable to think of or find a clean way to set a class static variables in php without setting them in each function. Is there anyway to have a setup like below.

```
class Foo{

    private static $bar;

    function __constructor(){
        self::$bar = new Object();
    }

    public static function test(){
        return self::$bar->call();
    }
}
```

Essential how can i set $bar to new Object() before every static call without setting it in test().

Comment: static variables are used when you need to set them only 1 time (during initialization) and do not change after

Comment: So I was thinking along that line since I know the above is bad practice. However, how would you go about implementing the above test function that needs to remain static?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5 is the answer

Comment: @EdHeal exactly what I need and I learned a new design pattern :)

Comment: @mschuett, You can also see my [`GIT`](https://github.com/sh4nx0r/SingleTon) that uses the SingleTon.

Comment: @Lashane, static variables are allowed to change, however only one variable exists regardless of the number of instances of the class.