# Call function inside class with $this

Tags: php

```
User::updatemain($set, $where);
```

This gives Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
My user class extends from Dbase class and here is user class function:

```
public static function activate($set, $where) {
    return $this->updatemain($set, $where);
```

here is dbase class (some part of):

```
private function query($sql = null, $params = null) {
    if (!empty($sql)) {
        $this->_last_statement = $sql;
        if ($this->_db_object == null) {
            $this->connect();
        }
        try {
            $statement = $this->_db_object->prepare($sql, $this->_driver_options);
            $params = Helper::makeArray($params);
                $x = 1;
                if (count($params)) {
                    foreach ($params as $param) {
                        $statement->bindValue($x, $param);
                        $x++;
                    }
                }
            if (!$statement->execute() || $statement->errorCode() != '0000') {
                $error = $statement->errorInfo();
                throw new PDOException("Database error {$error[0]} : {$error[2]}, driver error code is {$error[1]}");
                exit;
            }
            //echo $sql;
            return $statement;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $this->formatException($e);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

public function updatemain($set, $where) {
    return $this->query($sql, $params);
}
```

this is part of Dbase class

Comment: Try `$this::query($sql, $params);`

Comment: how about self::query($sql, $params);

Comment: I have tried but same arror again :(
how can i use self with private function query()

Comment: @fortune and @BeatAlex it will not work because query is not static `method` (it used `$this`)

Comment: it's pretty much said it all - you cannot use `$this` when you are not in an object context

Comment: @RoyalBg exactly so!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling static method so there is no `$this` in that context.

If you want to call other static method from given class then use `self::method()` but if you want to call non-static method you've got problem. First you have to create new object.

Answer (score 1):

When you use static methods, you can't use **$this** inside

```
public static function activate($set, $where) {
       return self::updatemain($set, $where);
}
```

Or you have to use singelton design

Comment: updateMain uses `query()` which is totally instance method ... :) it will not work this way. The idea behind static methods is that they are stateless.. in the OP design the architecture has way too many dependencies from the object

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Best solution - rewrite your class to one point access to DB object. And create Model classes to DB access. See my example code below:

**core AppCore**

```
<?php
class AppCore
{
    public static $config  = array();
    public static $ormInit = false;

    public static function init($config)
    {
        self::$config = array_merge(self::$config, $config);
    }

    public static function db($table)
    {
        // ORM - see http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest
        if (!self::$ormInit) {
            ORM::configure(self::$config['db']['connection']);
            ORM::configure('username', self::$config['db']['username']);
            ORM::configure('password', self::$config['db']['password']);
            self::$ormInit = true;
        }
        return ORM::for_table($table);
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
<?php
class UserModel
{
    const TABLE = 'user';

    public static function findById($u_id)
    {
        $result = AppCore::db(self::TABLE)->where('u_id', $u_id)->find_one();
        return $result ? $result->as_array() : null;
    }
}
```

**AppCore init section**

```
AppCore::init(array(
    'db' => array(
        'connection' => "mysql:dbname={$db};host={$host}",
        'username' => $user,
        'password' => $pass
    ),
));
```

i hope it help make your code better

Comment: When the things get horrible... just make them more horrible? The OP needs to fix all his domain logic. It's totally broken :)

Comment: @RoyalBg if i suggest use `ActiveRecord` and `singletone` it kill him:)

Comment: Most probably :) Btw. there's one more thing that will not work in updateMain - wrong variable names. It recieves $set and $where, but sends $sql and $params

Comment: @RoyalBg i don't really understand why people always write self DB class? A lot of frameworks and libraries exists now... For example http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: actually $params = $set, i tried to post whole both classes but i could not, i have singltone method in Dbase class

Comment: This actually isn't an implementation of the [singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/203359/777850), it's just a class with only static methods and properties and a `init` method...