# Have only one instance of a class

Tags: php, oop

I was wondering how I can get one instance of the following db connection.

For example, lets say this is my class in the file Database.php

```
public class Database {
    public function __construct() {
      try {
            // PDO Here
            print("Connected!");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```
Database();
Database();
```

Result

`Connected!Connected!`

I want to instantiate the class only once even if I call it twice.

Comment: Read about singleton pattern.

Comment: Read about singleton pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5

Comment: Damn, both of you guys beat me to it! But yea, singleton pattern entirely describes your question.

Comment: Thanks guys never heard of that but, now I do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a static variable to assign the Database class to and then use a if statement to check whether that variable has been instantiated.

There are many ways of doing this, but this is how I would do.

Database.php

```
public class Database
{
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
        try {
           // PDO Here
           print("Connected!");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
           die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        // Check is $_instance has been set
        if(!isset(self::$instance)) 
        {
            // Creates sets object to instance
            self::$instance = new Database();
        }

        // Returns the instance
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

index.php

```
 Database::getInstance();
 Database::getInstance();
```

Will only print "Connected!" once because the instance variable has been instantiated.

I recommend you to read [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) if you haven't heard of it. Look at the example codes they show, its not in PHP but it should be easy to understand.

EDIT:

In case you want to make the`getInstance` function short you can do the following.

```
return !isset(self::$instance) ? self::$instance = new self : self::$instance;
```