# Retrieving data from a singleton class PHP

Tags: php, static, singleton

I am trying to store file information to be passed around in the backend, so I created a singleton class with a static array and static methods accessing the array.

However when it comes to retrieving the data, I just get an empty array. Where am I going wrong here?

```
class FileStore {

private static $_tempFileData = array();
private static $initialized = false;

private function __construct() {}

private static function initialize() {
    if (self::$initialized)
        return;
    self::$initialized = true;
}

public static function storeTempFileData($data) {
    self::initialize();
    self::$_tempFileData[] = $data;
}

public static function getTempFileData() {
    self::initialize();
    return self::$_tempFileData;
}

public static function clearTempFileData() {
    self::initialize();
    unset(self::$_tempFileData);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you paste code where you store array and get it?

Comment: Singleton looks werid [Creating the Singleton design pattern in PHP5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is not a singleton, but a static class. Singleton assumes creating an instance of class.

In your code I see that `storeTempFileData` appends a value to static variable, but `getTempFileData` doesn't return the same value - it returns an array.

One more problem - after you unset `self::$_tempFileData`, it's not an array anymore. So `self::$_tempFileData[] = $data;` will trigger a notice.

Basically I think you need to change `self::$_tempFileData[] = $data;` to `self::$_tempFileData = $data;`.

Comment: correct after the first clear it won't work any more

Comment: Ok so if I wanted to just access that static array, add elements and retrieve the array, how would this be possible?

Comment: So you indeed wanted it to return an array rather than what you're setting in `storeTempFileData`? Ok, in this case, change `unset(self::$_tempFileData);` to `self::$_tempFileData) = array()`. Apart from this, the code seems to be correct. Please provide example code where you use this class and it doesn't work as expected.