# PDO Database class not stopping at catching exception

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have the following code within a PDO database class

```
/**
 * Class DB
 */
class DB{
    /**
     * @var DB The one and only instance of this class;
     */
    private static $theOneAndOnly = null;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $transactionalOptions = array( PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $nonTransactionalOptions = array( PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => true, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $transactionalDatabase = null;
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $nonTransactionalDatabase = null;
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $isConnected = false;

    /**
     * Initializes the connections to the database. One connection for transaction based operations and one connection
     * for non-transactional operations;
     */
    private function __construct(){
        if($this->isConnected() !== true){
            //connect
            if($this->connect() !== true){
                //connection failed
                exit( 'An internal error occurred. Please contact Keyfort support:' );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isConnected(){
        return $this->isConnected;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function connect(){
        try{
            $this->transactionalDatabase = new PDO(Config::DB_TYPE . ':host=' . Config::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . Config::$DB_NAME, Config::$DB_USER, Config::$DB_PASS, self::$transactionalOptions);
            $this->nonTransactionalDatabase = new PDO(Config::DB_TYPE . ':host=' . Config::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . Config::$DB_NAME, Config::$DB_USER, Config::$DB_PASS, self::$nonTransactionalOptions);

            $this->isConnected = true;

            return true;
        } catch(PDOException $exception){
            Log::error('Initializing the database connections failed:' . $exception->getTraceAsString());
            die();
            //return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return DB
     */
    public static function &getInstance(){
        if(self::$theOneAndOnly === null){
            self::$theOneAndOnly = new self();
        }

        return self::$theOneAndOnly;
    }

    public static function ParamMultiple($key){
        return self::Param($key) . ', ';
    }

    public static function Param($key){
        return ':' . $key;
    }

    /**
     * Close all connections;
     */
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function disconnect(){
        $this->transactionalDatabase = null;
        $this->nonTransactionalDatabase = null;
        $this->isConnected = false;
    }

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public function &getTransactional(){
        if($this->isConnected() !== true){
            $this->connect();
        }

        return $this->transactionalDatabase;
    }

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public function &getBasic(){
        if($this->isConnected() !== true){
            $this->connect();
        }

        return $this->nonTransactionalDatabase;
    }
}
```

It gets called via DB::getInstance();

The first time it gets called, it does not "die" if it errors.

I eventually get

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in C:\path\to\class\db.php on line 64
```

Line 64 is the $this->transactionalDatabase line.

It does log the exception in my error log (as in the catch).

I'm drawing a blank as to why its not "die"ing, I've tried alot of things, and I'm wondering if it could be starting 2 PDOs in the try?

[edit]
I'm running through the code with the wrong database user password currently. So I know what the error is caused by (it works ok when i put the correct password in), I just don't understand why it isn't processing the die() in the catch.

Use Fragment:

```
public static function GetByUsername($username){
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $dbh = $db->getBasic();

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . self::TABLE_NAME . ' WHERE ' . self::KEY_USERNAME . ' = ' . DB::Param(self::KEY_USERNAME);

    $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $statement->bindValue(DB::Param(self::KEY_USERNAME), $username);

    if($statement->execute() === true){
        $rawUser = $statement->fetch();
        if($rawUser === null){
            return null;
        } else {
            return self::CreateFromSelectResult($rawUser);
        }
    } else {
        Log::error("Fetching user by username failed:" . print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the fragment where you instantiate objects of this class.

Comment: i updated the question to include the class

Comment: I did ask for the object initialization and use fragment. not for full class description. something where you do `$DB = new DB;`

Comment: Sorry i should of been clearer. I added that "It gets called via DB::getInstance();" under the large part of code. I then added the class to explain what happens upon getInstance()

Comment: *It gets called via DB::getInstance();" under the large part of code.* that exactly what I need to help you. post the fragment of the page where you do those calls which brings the problem.

Comment: I posted an example of it's use, it gets called in a lot of places (because its meant to be singleton.). At the moment its erroring because im entering the wrong database user password, i just dont get why its not doing the "die()" and is carrying on

Comment: `because its meant to be singleton` I am not sure that you have a singleton here.

Comment: Oh, why? Its meant to be stored in " $theOneAndOnly " and the getInstance is meant to return " $theOneAndOnly" if its not null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/203359/4421474

Comment: thank you, should that help with it not doing the die() ? if i make it a singleton properly

Comment: I guess you should `public static function &getInstance(){
        static $theOneAndOnly = null;
        if($theOneAndOnly === null){
            $theOneAndOnly = new self();
        }

        return $theOneAndOnly;
    }`

Comment: My guess is not about `die()` but about `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` to fix

Comment: Ok, i changed as you said, but i get the same `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

Comment: I figured out my issue ... my first line of the catch `Log::Error('');' .... thats logged in the database, so it was infinitely looping through attempting to connect every time it tried to log the error. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was within "Log::error();"

Log:error() also tries to use the database.

So the issue was an infinite loop that started before the die() line was reached.

Answer (score 1):

Try using either transactionalDatabase or nonTransactionalDatabase, it should solve the problem.

Comment: do you mean changing the try to only include one or the other?

Comment: I figured out my issue ... my first line of the catch `Log::Error('');' .... thats logged in the database, so it was infinitely looping through attempting to connect every time it tried to log the error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your /tmp folder has space to cache queries.

Comment: This error is caused through wrong password, im trying to figure out why it doesnt stop when it can't get in the database. It's a website reliant on the database so in a perfect scenario i can get it to stop and display an error to the user

Comment: Sorry, what i'm mainly focusing on is the fatal error, this must be  happening before the script is killed. As a test, try increasing the memory say ini_set('memory_limit','16M'); Try 16,24,32.... This should be placed on the executing script. Again, i suppect that your server is running out of memory before it can finish processing the script.

Comment: In my PHP ini its set to 
`; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit=128M`
already, I'll have a go at increasing it

Comment: At `memory_limit=1024M` i get 574 new entries in the error log. At `2048` I get 761. I think I have an issue somewhere that it just keeps trying.

Comment: I figured out my issue ... my first line of the catch `Log::Error('');' .... thats logged in the database, so it was infinitely looping through attempting to connect every time it tried to log the error. Thank you so much for your help.