# Is it acceptable to call initialization methods inside a static class to avoid using an autoloader?

Tags: php, oop, constructor, static, init

Say I have a case where I need a helper class that should have static methods, but those methods need a static object to manipulate.

I would rather have the helper be self-contained, so I only have to include the file. Alternatively, one could add the initialization call to some kind of autoloader, but I would rather avoid that.

Considering that you can't use a `__construct` method here because the class is never instantiated, is this an acceptable alternative?

```
class HelperClass
{
  private static $property;
  private static function init()
  {
    if (!isset(self::$property))
      self::$property = new stdClass;
  }
  static function addSomething($key, $value)
  {
    self::$property->$key = $value;
  }
  static function getObject()
  {
    if (isset(self::$property))
      return self::$property;
    else
      return new stdClass;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you make a class with only static methods when you need an object anyway...

Comment: Well, at first this particular class was a trait, but it should be more of a service. The class has a bunch of static methods which build a JSON object in a standardized pattern for error reporting back to the client app. I don't want to instantiate this object over and over, I just want one central one with a global array of setters and getters.

Comment: You might wanna use Singleton Pattern then... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5

Comment: I've looked at using a singleton...this seems preferable, but if there's something WRONG with this way, then yes, I'll probably use a singleton.