# How can I make an object once for all methods?

Tags: php, oop

I have a code structure like this:

```
class myclass{

    use App/classes/Log

    public function myfunc1 () {

        $log_obj = new Log;
        $log_obj->log('something1');    

    }
    public function myfunc2 () {

        $log_obj = new Log;  
        $log_obj->log('something2');   

    }
    public function myfunc3 () {

        $log_obj = new Log;  
        $log_obj->log('something3');   

    }
}
```

In reality, I have 12 methods which I need to make a object of `Log` class in the most of them. Now I want to know, isn't there any better approach to I do that *(making an object)* once? For example using a `static` property and setting the object to it or whatever ..

Comment: If the method that you need to call isn't static - then creating an object like you are doing is the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating the Singleton design pattern in PHP5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5)

Comment: Why don't just assign the Log instance to a property of myclass and use it in those functions like $this->log?

Comment: @IgorSkoldin [I've already tested it](https://3v4l.org/5Yi2j) .. wont work.

Comment: Oh - I think I misunderstood the question. You could limit the creation of the Log object to just 1 by using the Singleton pattern for the Log class. Esentially you have a private constructor and a public method that will return a new instance of a Log object if there hasn't already been one created

Comment: @Chris Yes .. I'm trying to implement what you said kinda ..

Comment: @stack, this won't but if you use __construct for this it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the Log instance to a property of your myclass using __construct. Here's an example of accessing a method of a class inside another class:

```
class Test {
    public $var = 'test';

    public function show_var() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

class Test_2 {
    protected $test;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->test = new Test;
    }

    public function show_test() {
        $this->test->show_var();
    }

}

$test_2 = new Test_2;

$test_2->show_test();
```

See [here](https://3v4l.org/OWmC9) in action.