# php - Why is my getter method to get a static value inside a function not working?

Tags: php, sleep

I'm new to php, so I'm not sure if I can do this. I've a class which has a static variable which I'm periodically changing with the help of a static function like below. I'm reading the static  variable through a getter method in another static function.

infi_file.php

```
class infi_file {
    private static $value = 1;

    static function run_infinite ($interval) {
        while (true) {
            print date("H:i:s") . " - " . infi_file::$value . "\n";
            sleep ($interval);
            infi_file::$value = infi_file::$value ^ 1;
        }
    }

    static function getMode () {
        return infi_file::$value;
    }
}
```

run_infi_file.php

```
require_once "infi_file.php";

infi_file::run_infinite (5);
```

get_value.php

```
require_once "infi_file.php";

print infi_file::getMode () . "\n";
```

So I'm running both run_infi_file.php and get_value.php files simultaeously on 2 different terminal tabs.

While the output for run_infi_file is something like this :

> 15:11:51 - 1
>   15:11:56 - 0
>   15:12:01 - 1
>   15:12:06 - 0
>    ...

the output of get_value always seems to be **1**, even when the value is changed by run_infinite function. I thought that since $value is a static variable the entire class has just one copy which's used by all functions in that class. **Why is this not happening?**

Comment: are you sure that `infi_file::$value = infi_file::$value ^ 1;` is correct syntax? `$var = $var ^ 1` works like `$var++`?

Comment: yea, i guess it's bitwise xor, which is what i'm looking for

Comment: Create a singleton-patter for your infi_file-class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5

Comment: created a singleton pattern as you mentioned, still no change.

Comment: as per @PatrickManser 's comment,  if bitwise xor is what you are looking for, you are getting what you are looking for.  1^1 => 0, and 0^1 => 1. This is not about 'static variable access'. Change your ^ to a +

Comment: yea, the problem is with the 2nd output - get_value.php - it's always printing 1, irrespective of the values printed by run_infi_file.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use self for referring to static vars inside the class

```
    static function getMode () {
    return self::$value;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to self, still no change

Comment: You would have to change `infi_file::$value;` also in your `run_infinite` method!

Comment: yes  .. in .run_infinite  too .. .if you refer to an internal var in a class  inside a function you should use  self.

Comment: changed to self in all references inside the class

Answer (score 0):

A static function will not know of the other static methods and how they have affected variables AFAIK.