# Is it valid to predefine object of class even if we are using it or not?

Tags: php

I am just creating one class related to image upload and i was thinking to start it's object on end of the line of class that user can simply include it into file and execute it directly

Comment: Do you have a class which you only want one instance of? If so, take a look at [singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5).

Comment: No i was just thinking to call that class's object on the same file that user can directly call that object in that file after including that class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to create your upload image class with static function. So you never need to create object and you could include it in other class, whenever you want.

You could access your function as:

UploadImage::upload($destPath)